# array splice multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, splice

How do I scoop just the '$reference_cart_id' variable from this session_cart_array  so i can query db for other matching id's that belong to this customer? When i loop back through an undefined error comes up for `reference_id` & `reference_cart_id`.

```
cartOutput --Array
 (
 [0] => Array
    (
        [item_id] => 133
        [quantity] => 1
        [size] => MED
        [color] => Black
        [username] => medallion9
        [reference_cart_id] => DU3ZWRjNTkwNGYy
        [reference_id] => 6cefe27
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [item_id] => 134
        [quantity] => 1
        [size] => LG
        [color] => Camel-501
        [username] => medallion9
        [reference_cart_id] => DU3ZWRjNTkwNGYy
        [reference_id] => 6cefe27
    )
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_map` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$idArray = array_map(function($a){ return $a['reference_cart_id']; },$cartArray);
```

Comment: OK, so $a would now have the value of 'reference_cart_id'?.

Comment: $_SESSION["cart_array"]  is not storing the 'reference_cart_id'. Any suggestions why this occurs